# Display image from s3

Tags: html, node.js, amazon-s3, vue.js

I am trying to display images that I have uploaded to S3.  I believe the permissions are correct as I can hit the url and get data back.  However when I put the URL in an image tag I get a broken link.

When I put the image tag on my site in the network tab I see the call to s3 (with a 200 response) but an empty body.  If I hit the s3 url directly I get the data back and in the network tab I see the call WITH a response body from s3.

I'm uploading the images from a Vue frontend to an express/node backend.  I see the images fine in s3.

```
s3.putObject({
    Bucket: 'MYBUCKET',
    Key: `${result._id}-${file.upload.filename}`,
    Body: file.dataURL,
    ACL: 'public-read',
    ContentType: 'binary',
    ContentEncoding: 'utf8'
}, function (resp) {});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Xadvz/7327/

I use the data I get back from hitting s3 directly and it displays the image but when I put in the s3 url it displays a broken link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

S3 does not support `dataURL` data format.

In your backend:

1. convert dataURL to `buffer`
2. set ContentType of S3 object according to dataURL

code:

```
var regex = /^data:.+\/(.+);base64,(.*)$/;

var matches = file.dataURL.match(regex);
var ext = matches[1]; // image/jpeg
var data = matches[2]; // base64 string

var buffer = new Buffer(data, 'base64');

s3.putObject({
    Bucket: 'MYBUCKET',
    Key: `${result._id}-${file.upload.filename}`,
    Body: buffer, // upload binary
    ACL: 'public-read',
    ContentType: ext // set content type
}, function (resp) {});
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure `Content-Type: 'binary'` is correct? The value is identical to [MIME type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types). Here's some typical types:

***.jpg** .................................. `image/jpeg`

***.html** ................................. `text/html`

***.txt** ..................................... `text/plain`

***.mp3** .................................. `audio/mpeg`

**Unknown/Default** .............. `application/octet-stream`

`Content-Type` values must conform to the same syntax as MIME type:

```
type/sub-type
```

If you aren't sure you should at least use `application/octet-stream`

Comment: @ryandonohue, this is the likely answer, the [content type is wrong](https://imgur.com/a/PzXB1) on the url, please try with something else.